# Why do digimon names end in 'mon'?

Tags: digimon

As above, is there a special reason why digimon names end in mon?

[This](http://withthewill.net/threads/8345-Why-Digimon-have-quot-Mon-quot-at-the-end-of-their-names) thread says its for marketing but the guy also has the theory of:

> Digimon are digital lifeforms, and are made up of computer data, right? As we know, every kind of data file has an extension, or file format, for example a Microsoft Word document has ".doc" as its extension, a web page has ".html" and an image has ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif" etc, so perhaps the same thing applies for Digimon.
>
> by *wildwing64*

Comment: I believe is just an abbreviation of monster. pokemon = Pocket monster, digimon = digital monster

Comment: I didn't know that about pokemon :) Learn something new every day

Comment: Are you talking about the digimon names or the digimon title itself?

Comment: @MykAgustin I am talking about the names

Comment: @YuukiAsuna then saying that digimon = digital monster and pokemon as pocket monster doenst answer your question.

Comment: Its like saying that _hey, I'm a digimon my name ends in mon_ while we know that pokemon names doesn't .

Comment: @ᙈnlḭ๓ḭtḕᕍᏰᙈᖇຮt I don't understand your point?

Comment: I'm just saying that comparing digimon to pokemon isn't right. If your asking why digimon have mon in their names (Agumon,Gabumon,Tailmon) while pokemon doesn't (i.e. bulbasaur, pikachu, charmander)Except for the fact that both their **_titles_** end in _mon_. you clearly stated that your talking about the names right?

Comment: @ᙈnlḭ๓ḭtḕᕍᏰᙈᖇຮt I think you  should re-read my question. At no point do i even mention pokemon let alone compare it to digimon

Comment: @YuukiAsuna there's nothing wrong about your question, I was talking about the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Digimon is like Pokemon where ***Pokemon*** is short for ***Pocket Monsters***, that said ***Digimon*** is short for ***Digital Monsters***

this is visiable in most logos for Digimon

[image: Digimon Adventure 1]

[image: Digimon Adventure 2]

[image: Another Logo]

Also in the first episode of the 4Kids dub of Digimon Adventure when the Digi-destined come back together after finding their Digimon Partners the Digimon says in unision ([after Bukamon jumps off Joe's shoulder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4fRE_OK48E&t=11m00s))

> **Bukamon**: we are.....
>
> **All**: Digimon! Digital Monsters

Answer (score 7):

Just like what [Memor-X](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1587/memor-x) answered:

> Digimon is like Pokemon where Pokemon is short for Pocket Monsters, that said **Digimon** is short for **Digital Monsters**

The suffix **-mon** means monster as what the title also means.

**Name**

> The name of a Digimon species is usually based on its form, and **may be
> a pun**. For example, **Hyokomon**'s name and design are derived from the
> Japanese onomatopoeia for unsteady steps (「ひょこひょこ」 "Hyokohyoko"?), as
> well as the Chick (Gallus gallus domesticus) (雛 Hiyoko?). The
> species's name always ends in **"-mon"**.
>
> Digimon generally **do not have individual names**, and are instead simply
> referred to by the name of their species. So the word "Agumon",
> depending on the context it's used in, can either refer to the Digimon
> species or a single individual Digimon of that species. The Centarumon
> in Digimon Adventure and the Centarumon in Digimon Frontier share the
> same name because they are of the same species. However, they are not
> the same individual, and are different in appearance and voice.

Source: [Digimon (creature) Wikia](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Digimon_(creature))

**Digital Lifeforms**

As for the data file extension theory, here is a *possible* connection. Digimon have different attributes. We know that Digimon are digital lifeforms residing in the digital world.

From [Wikia](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Digimon_(creature)):

> Attribute
>
> Most Digimon species are classified into five attributes—**Data,
> Vaccine, Virus, Free, and Variable**. Most Digimon fall into the first
> three categories, with "Free" being rarer and "Variable" exclusive to
> Hybrid Digimon. Some Digimon either have their attributed by
> unidentified or lack them entirely.
>
> The main three attributes have a Rock, Paper, Scissors arrangement
> where Virus is generally advantaged against Data, Data is advantaged
> against Vaccine and Vaccine is advantaged against Virus. However,
> these attributes don't play a very important role in Digimon fights. A
> Digimon can generally defeat an opponent regardless of attribute if it
> is stronger than the opponent in Digivolution level and experience.

According to the thread you linked in [withthewill](http://withthewill.net/threads/8345-Why-Digimon-have-quot-Mon-quot-at-the-end-of-their-names):

> Digimon are digital lifeforms, and **are made up of computer data**, right? As we know, every kind of data file has an extension, or file format, for example a Microsoft Word document has ".doc" as its extension, a web page has ".html" and an image has ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif" etc, so perhaps the same thing applies for Digimon.
>
> Perhaps there is a file for every different Digimon (as in entire
> species, rather than singular Digimon), with that file format being
> ".mon", for example, the Agumon species filename would be
> "Agu.mon".

This theory is explained by Kira the Wanderer:

> I think it is what makes the most logic, **something that is not directly explained because it requires you to think**. "Dra" always refers to "dragon", "devi" to "devil", "Vam" to "Vampire, "De" to "demon" and so on. All the others have names that are a reference to something, whether it be a noise (Like Koromon) or otherwise. A file type does sound best and makes sense.

and ukyouluvr's explanation:

> **Grani from Tamers** was very obviously created as some kind of program. I wanna say that there was even a scene at some point that showed a computer display that read '**Grani.exe**'.

Zero ARMS: [Grani](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Grani) is a [ZERO-ARMS](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/ZERO-ARMS) whose name and design are derived from the mythological Grani, the steed of the hero Sigurd. It serves as a flying mount for Gallantmon.

> If you want to explore the theory
> further, that might be a good place to start looking.
>
> It could imply what **non-digimon digital lifeforms** are classified as.
> If **they are .exe filetypes**, then it would imply to me that non-digimon
> digital lifeforms are literally part of the program of the Digital
> World, making them something akin to forces of nature like Gravity. It
> fits well with the idea of Gennai & the Digi-gnomes. The D-Reaper
> and Grani were also created by programmers, and specifically referred
> to as 'programs' in the anime.

AngelosTheHero posted...

> It originated from Tamagotchi, which Digimon is born from; every
> Tamagotchi's name ends in -tchi, a cutesy Japanese suffix. While -mon
> is not a suffix, they followed the same convention of having something
> at the end of every creature's name.

That explains it, but still doesn't really justify the choice. Everyone realizes they're "Digital monsters"; not every creature needs a label. Oh well, at least it's fun. Also this might be due to making it more unique that in a way when you say a name like **Agumon** or **Greymon** anyone who hears it wouldn't say "*Those are Digimons, right?*" but would think exactly that "*Those are Digimons*" due to the -mon suffix.

Furthermore, all Digimon names have an **etymology/meaning**. For example, Birdramon means "Bird Dragon Monster". It also helps make non-Digimon digital entities seem even more alien/bizarre to the setting. For example, Eaters feel "wrong" because they are not even Digimon but an entire different thing/monster. If Digimon didn't have the -mon suffix, the effect would be lost and Eater would be "just another Digimon".

**PS**

As for my previous comment. It is just stated that the OP is asking about why the names of Digimon ended with -mon. The answer of Memor-X is **correct**, it's just that saying that Digimon is like Pokemon is somewhat not right. We know that Digimon names end with -mon if we're talking about the names, and for Pokemon, they don't. Its just because that Digimon is named with -mon at the end because it **may be a pun** invented by its creator.

**Trivia about Pokémon:**

At first, it is titled *Pocket Monsters*. However they shortened it to **Pokémon** for a catchier name and also because the term Pocket Monsters was already coined in the U.S.

> Pokémon is short for the original Japanese title of Pocket Monsters.
>
> The name Pokémon is the romanized contraction of the Japanese brand Pocket Monsters (ポケットモンスター Poketto Monsutā?), as such contractions are very common in Japan.

source: [Wikipedia-Pokemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon)

Comment: also Agu, Gabu, Tenta, Pal, Biyo, Gomo and Pata on their own sound more childish on their own lol. Introducing the NEW teletubbies.